# comparison between mapvalue and iterator c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, comparison, containers

I want to know if there is a way to compare two values to see if they are equal. I have a map where the key is int and the type is a class. And I want to find a specific number to see if it exists in the map and if it does a certain action should be done.

I.e: I have a bankaccount that I am storing in my map container. And i want to change the value of the balance for that account.

the int in my mapdeclaration is accountnumber.

```
map<int, class>::iterator it;
map<int, class>::myMap;



void Deposit(){
int banknbr;
int amount;
cout << "What is your acc numb?" << endl;
cin >> bankNbr;
for(it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++){
   if(it->first==myMap[bankNbr]){
     cout << "How much money do you wish to deposit?" << endl;
     cin >> amount;
     deposit(); // balance = balance + amount;
```

or anything like this perhaps. If I store two accounts i overwrite the balance of the first account. So if the first account has the balance 100 and the second 200 and I want to deposit 100 money in the first account, my value becomes 300 which is incorrect.

My code now is like this:

```
void deposit(int number){
int amount;
for(it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++){
    myMap.find(number);
    if(it != myMap.end(){
        cout << "How much money do you wish to deposit?"<<endl;
        cin >> amount;
            acc.deposit(amount); //acc is my own implemented class
            cout << "Your balance is: " << acc.getBal(number) << endl; //get bal is return balance
}
            }



}
```

Comment: Have you checked the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find shows that find returns the iterator to the found entry if found and otherwise end().  so you want `if (myMap.find(number) != myMap.end()) {}`

Comment: Your added code doesn't find anything. It just iterates over the entire map.  Instead of using a for loop, you should use the result of the myMap.find() function.

Comment: You are running the for loop to the size of your map `myMap`. The if condition becomes true as `it` is not equal to `map.end` and the amount is added. So the amount is added `sizeOfMap - 1` times. And the statement `myMap.find` has no effect. You can remove this statement and will get the same result. Check the edit I have made in the answer.

Comment: I have checked the docs.

Alright thanks for that new knowledge, did not know that the find() did not have any effect if I used the forloop. I shall try your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
for(it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++){ // it will iterate through all acounts
    myMap.find(number); // find returns an iterator BUT YOU DON'T ASSIGN IT
    if(it != myMap.end(){ // For each iteration this will be true, cause it is only changed in the for statement
```

`find` is the right way to handle this:

```
void Deposit(){
    int banknbr;

    cout << "What is your acc numb?" << endl;
    cin >> bankNbr;

    auto it = myMap.find(bankNbr);

    if(it != myMap.end()){
        int amount;

        cout << "How much money do you wish to deposit?" << endl;
        cin >> amount;
        it->second.deposit(amount);
        cout << "Your balance is: " << it->second.getBal() << endl; //get bal is return balance
    }
}
```

It looks like you had some misconceptions about how a `map` works so let me know if this is unclear.

Comment: Thanks, map just got more clearer for me with this explanation.  It made my code work correctly. So instead of using the created classobject I should use the mapped value to recall functions.

Comment: @SamGoat If I understand you correctly, yes. Your `map` should use account numbers as the keys and accounts as the values. So you can search the `map` by account numbers then operate on the account it is mapped to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `find` method of `map` to find whether the key exsists or not.

The `find` method returns an iterator if a key exists otherwise `map::end`

```
it=mymap.find(number);
if(it!=myMap.end()){
   //your code 
}
```

You can find more details of this method here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

```
 //for(it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++){
it = myMap.find(number);   //assign "it" 
if(it != myMap.end(){
    cout << "How much money do you wish to deposit?"<<endl;
    cin >> amount;
        acc.deposit(amount); //acc is my own implemented class
        cout << "Your balance is: " << acc.getBal(number) << endl; //get bal is return    balance
  }
       // }
```

Comment: `key_comp` returns a comparison object. It doesn't seem like it would be useful here.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it worked partially. I still got the update error on the balance when using acc.getBal() function. I needed the it->second.getBal() to make it work correctly.